# The stdout is constantly printing through expect script in nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, expect, spawn

what I wanna acheive.
I want to start humming bot with command and then enter password, then there comes the interactive interface where i can execute commands, it all runs in the same shell but inside humming bot instance. then I got couple of commands to run i.e. `'balance', 'gateway connect gamut'` etc.

---

but in my scenario i'm seeing that it loses the hummingbot input line and starts printing it's `stdout` console to the terminal which means

- if I run any hummingbot command, it executes on shell rather
  hummingbot input line.

so suggest me the best option to execute these.
the commands 'balance' or 'gateway connect gamut' will be executed through the apis, and one terminal/server instance for one user.

`First Function`

```
import { spawn } from 'child_process';
import { setHummingbotProcess } from '../../config';

// Create a function to spawn Hummingbot
export const startHummingbot = (passkey: string) => {
  const condaBinPath = '/home/mutahhirkhan/anaconda3/envs/hummingbot/bin/python';
  const hummingbotInstallPath = '/home/mutahhirkhan/Documents/daniel/hummingbot/bin/hummingbot.py';

  const expectScript = '/home/mutahhirkhan/Documents/daniel/hummingbot-server/src/utils/inputPassword.exp'
  // Construct the command to run Hummingbot
  const command = `${condaBinPath} ${hummingbotInstallPath}`;

  const hummingbotProcess = spawn('expect', [expectScript, command, passkey], { shell: true, stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe'] });

  //initialize the instance globally
  setHummingbotProcess(hummingbotProcess);

  hummingbotProcess.stdout.on('data', (data: string) => console.log(`stdout: ${data}`));

  hummingbotProcess.stderr.on('data', (data: string) => console.error(`stderr: ${data}`));

  hummingbotProcess.on('close', (code: string) => console.log(`Hummingbot process exited with code ${code}`));

  return hummingbotProcess;
};
```

`it's expect script`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set command1 [lindex $argv 0]
set command2 [lindex $argv 1]
set password [lindex $argv 2]

# Spawn Hummingbot
spawn [split $command1] $command2

expect "Enter your password:" {
  send "$password\r"
  # Simulate pressing Enter after entering the password
  send "\r"
}

# Allow some time for Hummingbot to execute commands
# expect eof  
interact
```

`2nd Function to list balances`

```
import { spawn } from 'child_process';
import { HUMMINGBOT_PROCESS } from '../../config';

// Create a function to spawn Hummingbot
export const listBalanceHandler = (command: string) => {
  console.log("killed ? ",HUMMINGBOT_PROCESS.killed);
  HUMMINGBOT_PROCESS.stdin.write(command ?? 'balance');
};
```

[image: humming bot interactive interface]